# Sqlitejdbc native dll mismatch.?

Tags: java, jar, sqlitejdbc

I have used Sqlitejdbc-v056.jar and respected native sqlitejdbc.dll. but the problem now is Just i have updated the old sqlitejdbc-v056.jar file with sqlitejdbc-3.7.2.jar and am using old native dll.

will it create a problem.? 
Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the pure Java SQLiteJDBC drivers really pure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238428/are-the-pure-java-sqlitejdbc-drivers-really-pure)

Comment: Try the type IV JDBC driver JAR.  It might be slower, but you won't require a .dll.

Comment: I have checked with this combination( New Sqlitejdbc3.7.2.jar and Old native dll) its working fine..!! am not sure wats really going on.!! o.O